# Track Android Apk download source (not Google play) for attribution campaign

Tags: android, android-studio, campaign-monitor, attribution, google-analytics-campaign-builder

I want to track the download source/url of my app when it is downloaded from a website url, for example: attribcamp.com/app.apk

I know about install_referrer but that works only if the campaign link sends someone to google play store to install the app.

Is it possible to track app download source when it is not installed from google play store?

Comment: What do you expect exactly? If someone redistributes your apps `.apk` file they have no obligation to include or tag any metadata on top of it

Comment: Inclusion of tag will be ensured by the third party. Let's just consider it as a mutual agreement where I will pay them for supporting my app's download from their server as part of their campaign.

Comment: Have you found a solution..? I am having the same issue   we have a lot of installs recently but I cannot attribute them ..

Comment: @AungMyintThein, I have implemented a custom solution with help from our backend team.

Comment: did you get a separate APK with special backend API to upload to apkpure?